# 2 практически одинаковые функции одна работает другая нет

Tags: javascript, jquery

В первой функции после изменения модального окна (изменение картинок) скрол (основной страницы) устанавливается в то положение в котором был.
Во второй функции, просто закрывается модальное окно, НО скрол основной страницы устанавливается в начала.

В чем именно проблема?

```js
//функция замены картинки, image - во модальном окне
function chimg(image){
 var artm = $(document).scrollTop(); //сохраняем значение скрола
 window.location.href = "#"; //закрываем старый блок
 window.location.href = "#"+image; //открываем новый блок
 $(document).scrollTop(artm);//устанавливаем скрол туда же где был
}

//функция закрытия модального окна
function clos(){
 var artmm = $(document).scrollTop(); //сохраняем значение скрола
 window.location.href = "#"; //закрываем блок
 $(document).scrollTop(artmm); //устанавливаем скрол туда же где был
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dal1' title='Далее' onclick=chimg('$dal2');>&raquo;</div>
<a href='#' class='iw_button' onclick=clos();>Х</a>
```

Comment: Я предполагаю что $(document).scrollTop()  не совсем то что вам нужно, вместо него используйте .offset() для элемента по которому был произведён клик

Comment: А что нужно? Если можно по проще.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая функция не выполняла скрол из-за того, что находилась в ссылке. После того как я вместо ссылки поставила div, она заработала.

С .offset() не справилась :) Слишком редко пользуюсь JS.